# Communication between USART and SPI

Tags: synchronous, stm32, spi, usart

Is it possible the communication between USART2 and SPI1 in stm32f10x??? 
I asked because USART2 clock works with APB1 and SPI1 clock works with APB2.
and in practice i could have communication between USART1 and SPI1 but couldnt with USART2.

Comment: What is your microcontroller exactly? Are you sure they are connected correctly on the baord?

Comment: Its stm32f103VET6 . yes i'm sure.

Comment: To ensure proper communication between USART2 and SPI1, you need to configure their clock sources and respective baud rates, and also configure the GPIO pins that are used for data transmission and reception.

Answer (score 0):

Well irrespective of clock , you can communicate with individual peripherals. APB1 and APB2 are just clock sources and it should not impact the communication.